# Join the every two lines from output with space delimiter and format the output in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a script to pull the data from Directory manger LDAP  `ldapsearch` command to get the `user` and `user manger name` for some validation. as a newbie learner i have written below code in python3 which yeilds the data, basically user and user manager's name:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
##  script Name: getUserinfo.py
import subprocess
from subprocess import call

# Authentication
'''ldap_dn = "cn=directory manager"
ldap_pwd = ""
ldap_server = "its3.rraka.com"
ldap_base = "ou=people,o=rraka.com"
ldap_user_file = "uid.txt"' '''

def CheckID(user):
  call("ldapsearch -h server1 -D 'cn=directory manager' -w mypass123 -LLLb 'ou=people,o=rraka.com' managerlogin uid=" + user , shell=True)

def UidCheck():
  with open( '/home/karn/uid.txt', mode='rt', encoding='utf-8' ) as f:
    for line in f.readlines() :
      return CheckID(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    UidCheck()
```

My above script returns the results as below which is good data what i want, but need to parse this data to be more readable, like to print user and User manager.

```
# ./getUserinfo.py

dn: uid=cecile,ou=people,o=rraka.com
managerlogin: simonk

dn: uid=richardb,ou=people,o=rraka.com
managerlogin: hxl

dn: uid=wwoo,ou=people,o=rraka.com
managerlogin: mstanton

dn: uid=ski,ou=people,o=rraka.com
    managerlogin: fkahn

------------ further ouput turnicated deliberately ----------
```

> Expected ouput would be:

```
User ID         Manger ID
--------------------------------
cecile          simonk
richardb        hxl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the code working after a little more modification and indded a great help from @kaidokuuppa for the idea of using Dictionary and data parsing.

here is the working code snippet..

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
##  script Name: getUserinfo.py
import subprocess
from subprocess import call

def CheckUid(user):    
    proc = subprocess.Popen("ldapsearch -h server1 -D 'cn=directory manager' -w mypass123 -LLLb 'ou=people,o=rraka.com'  'uid=%s' managerlogin" % (user), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    info_str = proc.stdout.read().decode('utf8')
    split_str = info_str.split()
    print({'UserID': split_str[1].split(',')[0].split('=')[1], 'MangerID': split_str[-1]})

def CallUid():
    with open('uid.txt', mode='rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       for line in f.readlines():
         CheckUid(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CallUid()
```

> Now the result is produced as:

```
# ./getUserinfo.py
    {'UserID': 'amitnegi', 'MangerID': 'suhas'}
    {'UserID': 'anagpal', 'MangerID': 'benjamin'}
    {'UserID': 'bharattp', 'MangerID': 'fkahn'}
    {'UserID': 'bhavin', 'MangerID': 'mbao'}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you want to save output of `ldapsearch` command to a variable and parse the string to a data structure. [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is a good choice. The parsing can be done in a somewhat crude manner

```
def checkID(user):
    proc = subprocess.Popen("ldapsearch -h server1 -D 'cn=directory manager' -w mypass123 -LLLb 'ou=people,o=rraka.com' managerlogin uid=" + user, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    info_str = proc.stdout.read().decode('utf8')
    #parsing phase
    split_str = info_str.split()
    return {'uid': split_str[1].split(',')[0].split('=')[1],
         'manager': split_str[-1]}
```

Modifying your code a little bit to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) we get a list of dictionaries.

```
def UidCheck():
  with open( '/home/karn/uid.txt', mode='rt', encoding='utf-8' ) as f:
    return [checkID(line) for line in f.readlines()]
```

And in the main function you write that dictionary in the desired format.

```
from io import StringIO
from csv import DictWriter

if __name__ = '__main__':
    fileobj = StringIO()
    writer = DictWriter(fileobj, fieldnames=['uid', 'manager'], delimiter='\t')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(UidCheck())
    print(fileobj.getvalue())
```

Or if you prefer a file

```
with open('/path/to/a/file.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
    writer = DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=['uid', 'manager'], delimiter='\t')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(UidCheck())
```

Comment: kaidokuuppa .. when the run the suggested code it just stucks